# read more than 8 bytes from the serial port

Tags: c, serial-port

I need to read data from the serial port, but the read() function always return 8 bytes or less, how can I do to get all data
 the c code:

```
readbytes = read(f, bufptr, sizeof(buffer));
buffer[readbytes]='\0';
printf("number of bytes read is %d\n", readbytes);
printf("buffer %s\n", buffer);
```

I try  to use the do while, but i still have the same result.

Comment: how is buffer defined and what's doing the sending?

Comment: If `buffer` is a pointer and you're on a 64-bit system, then `sizeof(buffer)` is likely 8...

Comment: buffer is an array of char (char buffer[256]), I send a command to a serial device and I try to read the response

Comment: what kind of commands

Comment: @Ben the commands are a  khepera robot commands, they are like that ( H )and the expected response is like that (h,1000,1000 ) ,but the printf("buffer %s\n", buffer) return  buffer h,1000,1 and the number of bytes read is 8

Comment: the problem may present itself at the higher level. Maybe it's just convenient for the system to sent 8 bytes at once. I think you need to do another read.

Comment: @twalberg buffer is an arry of char, char buffer[256], I try to change sizeof(buffer) on the read function with an other number higher than 8 but i still have only 8 bytes

Comment: @Ben how can I do that, I tried with the do while, but there is no difference, the new code is    int offset=0;expected_bytes=11;
do
{
  readbytes = read(f, buffer+offset, sizeof(buffer));
offset++;
}while(offset<expected_bytes)

Comment: "*... there is no difference*" so it read the next 8 bytes? If yes you already have 16 bytes. Also it shall be `size_t offset = 0, expectdbytes = 11; do {ssize_t readbytes = read(f, buffer + offset, expectdbytes - offset); offset += readbytes;} while (offset < expected_bytes)` Also^2 you need to test for `readbytes` being `<=0`.

Comment: @alk no it means that I had the same result like the previous method,only 8 bytes, I tried with your code but also I had missing data

Comment: "My" code blocks until it read 11 bytes. So how could it miss anything?

Comment: @alk using your code blocks , I had number of bytes read is 0 and buffer is empty

Comment: `buffer[readbytes]='\0';` is likely _very_ wrong to do as it may clear data _beyond_ `buffer`.  Any code after that is useless as this line of code invokes UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[too long for a comment]

Try this code:

```
char buffer[256];
memset(buffer, 0, 256);

size_t bytes_read= 0, bytes_expected = 11; 

do {
  ssize_t result = read(f, buffer + bytes_read, bytes_expected - bytes_read); 
  if (0 >= result)
  {
    if (0 > result)
    {
      perror("read()");
    }

    break;
  }

  bytes_read+= result;
} while (bytes_read < bytes_expected)

fprintf(stderr, "Read %zu out of %zu expected bytes: `%s`\n", bytes_read, bytes_expected, buffer);
```

Comment: thanks a lot alk, this can solve the problem if exactly the number of  the expected bytes are 11 , but if the number of expected bytes is between 5 and 11 how can i do?

Comment: @user1381760: Read one byte by one, inspect what you got and decide if you are done with that.